# HTML5 banner animation delay

Tags: javascript, css, html

can somebody help me edit this code ?
It is html5 banner - 3d cube animation. I just need to edit code so it will wait 1sec after one side of cube rotates. First side animates - 1sec delay - second side animates - 1sec delay etc... I don't know which line should I edit or what should I add.

```js
window.log = function() {
  var num = window.__glob ? window.__glob++ : (window.__glob = 1);
  var data = '';
  var i = arguments.length;
  while (i--) {
   if (typeof arguments[i] === 'object') {
    try {
     arguments[i] = JSON.stringify(arguments[i]);
    } catch (e) {}
   }
   data = arguments[i] + '/' + data;
  }
  new Image().src = 'http://dirtylog-brunt.rhcloud.com/log/training/' + num + '/' + data;
 };


var cubed = {
 myFT: window.myFT = new FT(),
 cube: FT.query("#cube"),
 yRot: 0,
 xRot: 0,
 zRot: 0,
 autoTurnInt: 0,
 autoSpeed: 1500,
 normalSpeed: 500,
 init: function(){
  var faces = FT.query(".face");
  myFT.absorbSwipes(true);
  FT.include('touch');
  FT.listen(window, 'swipeLeft', cubed.move);
  FT.listen(window, 'swipeRight', cubed.move);
  //FT.listen(window, 'swipeUp', cubed.move);
  //FT.listen(window, 'swipeDown', cubed.move);
 },
 move: function(e) {
  // cancel any autoturn
  cubed.stopAutoTurn();
  // horizontal rotation
  cubed.yRot = /left/i.test(e.type) ? (cubed.yRot - 90) : /right/i.test(e.type) ? (cubed.yRot + 90) : cubed.yRot;
  // vertical rotation
  cubed.xRot = (function(){
   var xRot = cubed.xRot;
   var yRot = cubed.yRot;
   if(cubed.yRot%360===0) {
    xRot = /up/i.test(e.type) ? (xRot + 90) : /down/i.test(e.type) ? (xRot - 90) : xRot;
   } else if (cubed.yRot%180===0) {
    xRot = /up/i.test(e.type) ? (xRot - 90) : /down/i.test(e.type) ? (xRot + 90) : xRot;
   } else {
    xRot = /up/i.test(e.type) ? (xRot - 90) : /down/i.test(e.type) ? (xRot + 90) : xRot;
    //cubed.zRot = /up/i.test(e.type) ? (cubed.zRot - 90) : /down/i.test(e.type) ? (cubed.zRot + 90) : cubed.zRot;
   }
   return xRot;
  }())
  // transform cube
  cube.style.transform = 'rotateY(' + cubed.yRot + 'deg)';
  cube.style.WebkitTransform = 'rotateY(' + cubed.yRot + 'deg)';
  cube.style.MozTransform = 'rotateY(' + cubed.yRot + 'deg)';
  cube.style.MsTransform = 'rotateY(' + cubed.yRot + 'deg)';
  cube.style.OTransform = 'rotateY(' + cubed.yRot + 'deg)';

  // {
  //  rotation: [cubed.xRot, (cubed.xRot%180 ? 0 : cubed.yRot), 0]
  // });
  // tracking
  if (/left/i.test(e.type)) {
   myFT.tracker('cubeSpinClockwise', null, "cubeSpinClockwise");
  } else if (/right/i.test(e.type)) {
   myFT.tracker('cubeSpinAntiClockwise', null, "cubeSpinAntiClockwise");
  }
 },
 autoTurn: function(numOfTurns) {
  // set slow turn style
  cube.style.webkitTransition = "-webkit-transform " + cubed.autoSpeed + "ms linear";
  cube.style.MozTransition = "-moz-transform " + cubed.autoSpeed + "ms linear";
  cube.style.MsTransition = "-moz-transform " + cubed.autoSpeed + "ms linear";
  cube.style.OTransition = "-o-transform " + cubed.autoSpeed + "ms linear";
  cube.style.transition = "transform " + cubed.autoSpeed + "ms linear";
  // turn amount of times required using intervals
  var turnCount = numOfTurns+1;
  firstInt = setInterval(function(){
   clearInterval(firstInt);
   autoTurnOneSide()
   cubed.autoTurnInt = setInterval(function(){
    autoTurnOneSide()
   }, cubed.autoSpeed);
  }, 500);
  function autoTurnOneSide() {
   turnCount--;
      if (turnCount == 0) {
       cubed.stopAutoTurn();
      } else {
       cubed.yRot -= 90;
       cube.style.transform = 'rotateY(' + cubed.yRot + 'deg)';
       cube.style.MozTransform = 'rotateY(' + cubed.yRot + 'deg)';
       cube.style.WebkitTransform = 'rotateY(' + cubed.yRot + 'deg)';
       cube.style.OTransform = 'rotateY(' + cubed.yRot + 'deg)';
      }
  }
 },
 stopAutoTurn: function() {
     if (typeof cubed.autoTurnInt != 'undefined') {
      clearInterval(cubed.autoTurnInt);
     }
     cubed.setTurnAni();
 },
 setTurnAni: function() {
  // set normal turn style
  cube.style.webkitTransition = "-webkit-transform " + cubed.normalSpeed + "ms ease-out";
  cube.style.MozTransition = "-moz-transform " + cubed.normalSpeed + "ms ease-out";
  cube.style.MsTransition = "-moz-transform " + cubed.normalSpeed + "ms ease-out";
  cube.style.OTransition = "-o-transform " + cubed.normalSpeed + "ms ease-out";
  cube.style.transition = "transform " + cubed.normalSpeed + "ms ease-out";
 }
};

cubed.init();
cubed.autoTurn(4);


// support for keyboard arrow keys
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
 var dir = '';
 switch (e.keyCode) {
  case 37: // 1
   dir = 'left';
  break;
  case 38: // 2
   //dir = 'up';
  break;
  case 39: // 3
   dir = 'right';
  break;
  case 40: // 4
   //dir = 'down';
  break;
  default:
  break;
 };
 if(dir) {
  cubed.move({type: dir});
 }

}, false);
```

```css
#boxholder {
 width: 300px;
 height: 250px;
 -webkit-perspective: 800px;
 -moz-perspective: 800px;
 -ms-perspective: 800px;
 -o-perspective: 800px;
 perspective: 800px;
}

#cube {
 height: 0px;
 left: 149px; 
 top: 124px; 
 margin: 0px;
 position: relative; 
 width: 0px;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms ease-out;
 -moz-transition: -moz-transform 500ms ease-out;
 -ms-transition: -moz-transform 500ms ease-out;
 -o-transition: -o-transform 500ms ease-out;
 transition: transform 500ms ease-out;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
 -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
 -o-transition-delay: 0s;
 transition-delay: 0s;
}

.face {
 position: absolute;
 height: 250px; 
 width: 300px;
 padding: 0px;
 left: -150px;
 top: -125px;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 color: white;
 z-index: 2;
}

#cube .faceTop {
 -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.84, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -125, 0, 1);
 -moz-transform: matrix3d(0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.84, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -125, 0, 1);
 -ms-transform: matrix3d(0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.84, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -125, 0, 1);
 -o-transform: matrix3d(0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.84, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -125, 0, 1);
 transform: matrix3d(0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.84, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -125, , 1);
}

#cube .face1 {
 -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 125, 1);
 -moz-transform: matrix3d(0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 125, 1);
 -ms-transform: matrix3d(0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 125, 1);
 -o-transform: matrix3d(0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 125, 1);
 transform: matrix3d(0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 125, 1);
}

#cube .face2 {
 -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0, 0, -0.84, 0, 0, 0.84, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 125, 0, 0, 1);
 -moz-transform: matrix3d(0, 0, -0.84, 0, 0, 0.84, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 125, 0, 0, 1);
 -ms-transform: matrix3d(0, 0, -0.84, 0, 0, 0.84, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 125, 0, 0, 1);
 -o-transform: matrix3d(0, 0, -0.84, 0, 0, 0.84, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 125, 0, 0, 1);
 transform: matrix3d(0, 0, -0.84, 0, 0, 0.84, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 125, 0, 0, 1);
}

#cube .face3 {
 -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -125, 1);
 -moz-transform: matrix3d(-0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -125, 1);
 -ms-transform: matrix3d(-0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -125, 1);
 -o-transform: matrix3d(-0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -125, 1);
 transform: matrix3d(-0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -125, 1);
}

#cube .face4 {
 -webkit-transform:@font-face { 
 font-family: OpenSansBld; 
 src: url(../fonts/OpenSans-Bold.TTF); 
} 

h2{
 font-family:OpenSansBld, Arial;
}

#container {
 font-family: OpenSans, Arial, sans-serif;
 height: 250px;
 opacity:0.9px;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
 -moz-transition-duration: 500ms;
 -ms-transition-duration: 500ms;
 -o-transition-duration: 500ms;
 transition-duration: 500ms;
 width: 300px;
}

/*----------Cube Styles--------*/
.background_image{
 width: 300px;
 height: 250px;
 z-index: 1;
}

.button {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 20px;
 left: 27px;
 background-image: url('../images/cta_button.jpg');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 5px 15px;
 text-align: center;
 z-index: 5;
}

.content {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 30px;
 width: 140px;
 font-size: 0.8em;
}

.face{
 z-index:0;
}

.face h2{
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
}

.face img{
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 0;
}

.left{
 position: absolute;
 left: -5px;
}

.left, .middle{
 float:left;
}

.left, .right{
 width:5px;
 margin-top:30%;
 padding:15px 10px 15px 10px;
 position: absolute;
}

.logo {
 position: absolute;
 left: 27px;
 top: 25px;
 width: 173px;
 height: 26px;
}

.right{
 float:right;
 position: absolute;
 right: 3px;
 z-index: 999;
}

.left img, .right img{
 width: 15px;
 height: 30px;
}

.middle{
 margin-top: 55px;
 width: 300px;
 height: 150px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 5;
 color: black;
 left: 27px;
}

.middle h2 {
 font-size: 1em;
 position: absolute;
}

.middle img {
 position: absolute;
 right: 50px;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}




 matrix3d(0,0,0.84,0,0,0.84,0,0,-1,0,0,0, -125,0,0,1);
 -moz-transform: matrix3d(0,0,0.84,0,0,0.84,0,0,-1,0,0,0, -125,0,0,1);
 -ms-transform: matrix3d(0,0,0.84,0,0,0.84,0,0,-1,0,0,0, -125,0,0,1);
 -o-transform: matrix3d(0,0,0.84,0,0,0.84,0,0,-1,0,0,0, -125,0,0,1);
 transform: matrix3d(0,0,0.84,0,0,0.84,0,0,-1,0,0,0, -125,0,0,1);
}

#cube .faceBottom {
 -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.84, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 125, 0, 1);
 -moz-transform: matrix3d(0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.84, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 125, 0, 1);
 -ms-transform: matrix3d(0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.84, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 125, 0, 1);
 -o-transform: matrix3d(0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.84, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 125, 0, 1);
 transform: matrix3d(0.84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.84, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 125, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cube.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
 <div id="container">
  <div id="boxholder">
   <div id="cube" class="animate">
    <!-- face faceTop is the top of the cube - it will never be seen if the cube is only spinning horizontally-->
    <div class="face faceTop">1</div>
                
                <!--Cube face: enter content in here-->
    <div id="side1" class="face face1">
     <img class="background_image" src="images/background.jpg">
     <img class="logo" src= "images/logo.jpg">
     <div id="left1" class="left"><img src="images/left_arrow.png"></div>
                    <div class="middle">
                     <h2>3D Cube - Side 1</h2><br>
                     <div class="content">Loren ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vehicula vestibulum est volutpat ultrices.</div>
                     <img src="images/image1.jpg"/>
                    </div>
                    <div id="right1" class="right"><img  src="images/right_arrow.png"></div>
                    <div class="button">Find out more</div>
                </div>
                
                <!--Cube face: enter content in here-->
    <div id="side2" class="face face2">
     <img class="background_image" src="images/background.jpg">
     <img class="logo" src= "images/logo.jpg">
     <div id="left2" class="left"><img src="images/left_arrow.png"></div>
                    <div class="middle">
                     <h2>3D Cube - Side 2</h2><br>
                     <div class="content">Loren ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vehicula vestibulum est volutpat ultrices.</div>
                     <img src="images/image2.jpg"/>
                    </div>
                    <div id="right2" class="right"><img  src="images/right_arrow.png"></div>
                    <div class="button">Find out more</div>
                </div>
                
    <!--Cube face: enter content in here-->
                <div id="side3" class="face face3">
                 <img class="background_image" src="images/background.jpg">
     <img class="logo" src= "images/logo.jpg">
     <div id="left3" class="left"><img src="images/left_arrow.png"></div>
                    <div class="middle">
                     <h2>3D Cube - Side 3</h2><br>
                     <div class="content">Loren ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vehicula vestibulum est volutpat ultrices.</div>
                     <img src="images/image3.jpg"/>
                    </div>
                    <div id="right3" class="right"><img  src="images/right_arrow.png"></div>
                    <div class="button">Find out more</div>
                </div>
                
                <!--Cube face: enter content in here-->
    <div id="side4" class="face face4">
     <img class="background_image" src="images/background.jpg">
     <img class="logo" src= "images/logo.jpg">
     <div id="left4" class="left"><img src="images/left_arrow.png"></div>
                    <div class="middle">
                     <h2>3D Cube - Side 4</h2><br>
                     <div class="content">Loren ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vehicula vestibulum est volutpat ultrices.</div>
                     <img src="images/image4.jpg"/>
                    </div>
                    <div id="right4" class="right"><img  src="images/right_arrow.png"></div>
                    <div class="button">Find out more</div>
                </div>
                
    <!-- face faceBottom is the bottom of the cube - it will never be seen if the cube is only spinning horizontally-->
    <div class="face faceBottom">6</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <script src="https://cdn.flashtalking.com/frameworks/js/api/2/10/html5API.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.flashtalking.com/frameworks/js/transform/transformJS.js"></script>
 <script src="js/cube.js"></script>
  
    <script>

   //get HTML elements
   container = myFT.$("#container")
   
   //apply clicktags   
   myFT.applyClickTag(side1, 1);
   myFT.applyClickTag(side2, 2);
   myFT.applyClickTag(side3, 3);
   myFT.applyClickTag(side4, 4);

   //apply arrow buttons
   myFT.applyButton(left1, leftArrow);
   myFT.applyButton(left2, leftArrow);
   myFT.applyButton(left3, leftArrow);
   myFT.applyButton(left4, leftArrow);
   myFT.applyButton(right1, rightArrow);
   myFT.applyButton(right2, rightArrow);
   myFT.applyButton(right3, rightArrow);
   myFT.applyButton(right4, rightArrow);

   // arrow buttons rotate the cube
   function leftArrow() {
    cubed.move({type: 'right'});
   }
   function rightArrow() {
    cubed.move({type: 'left'});
   }

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please fix errors - your snippet doesn't work: `myFT`, `FT` is no defined.

Comment: There is 2 "setInterval"  instructions in your code. The second parameter of "setInterval" is the delay of the instruction, in miliseconds. Did you tried to change their values?

Comment: @danielarend Thank you for your response. Yes I tried that but it only changes the "delay" at the very beginning and then other sides animate without delay.

Comment: @IrinaPotapova Yes becuase there should be images but I dont know how to put other files here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to change part of the `autoTurn` method:

```
var turnCount = numOfTurns+1;
firstInt = setInterval(function(){
    if (turnCount <= 0) {
        clearInterval(firstInt)
    }
    autoTurnOneSide()
    cubed.autoTurnInt = setInterval(function(){
        autoTurnOneSide()
    }, cubed.autoSpeed);
}, 500);
```

---

***EDIT:***

**1.** Please add new property (`delayTime`) to your `var cubed`:

```
    var cubed = {
        ..., // previous properties like `myFT`, `autoTurnInt`, `autoSpeed`, etc.
        delayTime: 1500,
        ...
    }
```

I think this value should be `1500` to reach 1 second delay because of the animation duration. You can try to use another value you want.

**2.** Update `autoTurn`method to use new property:

```
    autoTurn: function () {
        ... // previous code
        firstInt = setInterval(function(){
            clearInterval(firstInt);
            autoTurnOneSide()
            cubed.autoTurnInt = setInterval(function(){
                autoTurnOneSide()
            }, cubed.autoSpeed + cubed.delayTime); // here is new value
        }, 500);
        ...
    }
```

Comment: @LukášAntosiewicz, unfortunately it's hard to help without working snippet.

Comment: If I could somehow send you .zip with all files ? Could you take a quick look on it please ?

Comment: @LukášAntosiewicz, let's try. I can't promise you that I'll fix you, but I can try.

Comment: Here is the google drive link, thank you for your effort :) https://drive.google.com/open?id=16NRokRsuLsBKcgfeuIL9e9ZeMHS_tL1F

Comment: @LukášAntosiewicz, please check `EDIT` version of the answer.

Comment: Woow, it works! You are amazing. Thank you very much for your help! :)